# systrace export as log formats like csv or text file instead of html

Tags: systrace

can we export systrace output as CSV file, so that i can parse and generate report.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in facility for generating reports in different formats.  However, if you look at the HTML, you can see that it's split into a block of javascript code that implements the viewer, followed by the data, one entry per line.  Writing a script that converts the data to the format of your choice is straightforward.